# This line crashes the page on my web host but not on my localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, xpath, syntax, domdocument

```
$title = $xpath->query("span[@class='item_list']",$item)[0];
```

I can't figure out why it only works when I omit this line on my web host. localhost seems normal and functional as intended. This is used on a template in Wordpress 4.9.4. I have no idea what the PHP version of the host is. This line is inside a loop of another xpath query which works with the page if that line above is cut out:

```
foreach( $xpath->query("//div[@class='product_list']") as $item) {    }
```

Could there be a limitation set in php on my web host that prevented me to do more than one query? or nested query perhaps?

Comment: Crashes how? Does it give any error messages? You may need to look at the server error logs for any information.

Comment: What happens if you do `$matches = $xpath->query("span[@class='item_list']",$item); $title = $matches[0];`

Comment: @aynber It displays blank content. The header is left out, probably because get_header() is at the top. Do I have access to the server error logs in wordpress?

Comment: @PatrickQ It still shows no result

Comment: It could be that your first query doesn't match anything - so when you try and use [0] it will fail with no element.  You should check if it returns anything before assuming it has even 1 element.

Comment: @NigelRen The first query should have results considering my localhost has shown the result and also by omitting this line, it displays the said result

Comment: The error logs would be on the server somewhere, but not accessible by Wordpress. You can look in the Wordpress directory for an `error.log` file, or you can check wherever the host puts the error logs.

Comment: @aynber Thanks. I managed to get the error using this [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/4188998) inserted on the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node lists can not be treated as arrays in older PHP  versions (< 5.6.3).

Here are several approaches to avoid the problem.

### Use the `->item()` method

```
$titleNode = $xpath->query("span[@class='item_list']",$item)->item(0);
```

### Use a limit in Xpath

```
foreach ($xpath->query("span[@class='item_list'][1]",$item) as $titleNode) {
  //...
}
```

This limits the nodes in the node list to the first one. The `foreach()` can be executed once for the first node or not if the Xpath expression fails to match a node. It is a nice shortcut to validate if here is a title node to handle.

### Fetch the text content directly

```
$titleString = $xpath->evaluate("string(span[@class='item_list'])",$item);
```

Xpath expressions can return the result a scalar variable (string, number, boolean). This works only with `DOMxpath::evaluate()`. `string()` casts the first matched node into a string (returns its text content). It returns an empty string if no node was matched.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39030256/4188998) solved my issue. The culprit came out when I turned on error reporting on the script and showed me this:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array
```

I referenced the error and learned that it was caused by the different PHP versions between my localhost and web host as I initially suspected.