# How to grab an HTML file with php XPath

Tags: php, html, xpath

I have the following portion of an HTML file:

```
<span class="type">Servers:</span>
    <li class="server">
        <span class="bullet">-</span>
        <span class="label"></span> (19345)
        <ul class="components">
            <span class="type">Components:</span>
            <li class="component">
            <span class="bullet">+</span>
            <span class="label">WebSphere:APPLICATION_SERVER</span> (18234)
            <ul class="applications">
                <span class="type">Applications:</span>
                    <li class="application">
                        <span class="bullet">+</span>
                        <span class="label">Ipostmutuaintra</span> (981)
                            <ul class="transactions">
                                <span class="type">Transactions:</span>
                                <li class="transaction">
                                    <span class="label">/IpostMutuaIntra</span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="transaction">
                                    <span class="label">/IpostMutuaIntra//importo/pdfInoltrata/A_*
```

I'd want to grab the texts between the tags:

```
Servers: 19345
Components: WebSphere:APPLICATION_SERVER (18234)
Applications: Ipostmutuaintra
Transactions: /IpostMutuaIntra
              /IpostMutuaIntra//importo/pdfInoltrata/A_*
```

and stored them in an array.
I write the following code that is a function called from another main script, in which I use the XPath method:

```
<?php

$heading=parseToArray($xpath);
    
print_r ($heading);
//echo "Script eseguito sul server " . strtoupper($heading[1]) ." relativo alla directory " . substr($heading[4],9,-21);
    
function parseToArray($xpath)
{

    //$xpathquery="//span[@class='".$class1."'][.='ITCAM for AD/WebSphere/J2EE']/following-sibling::ul/li[@class='".$class2."']/span";
    $xpathquery="//span[@class='label'][.='Servers:']";
    $elements = $xpath->query($xpathquery);
    
    if (!is_null($elements)) {
        $resultarray=array();
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            $nodes = $element->childNodes;
            foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                $resultarray[] = $node->nodeValue;
            }
        }
        return $resultarray;
    }
}
?>
```

It grabs only "Servers:", but I am not able to go on.
How to get the other text as I want?

Answer (score 1):

If you start with the `p` that surrounds the Servers: `span` it becomes easier to get the siblings like so:

```
$xpathquery="//p[./span[@class='type'][.='Servers:']]/following-sibling::ul/li";
```

This code allows me to get all the text you want but it still requires parsing the individual bits out since the input is rather unstructured.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want from all `<span class="type">` the available label's.

I would first need use this xpath:

```
//ul[ ancestor-or-self::ul[span[@class='type' and text()='Servers:']]][span[@class='type']]
```

this will give you every `ul` with child `span` that has a `@class` attribute with the value `type` and ha a `ancestor-or-self::ul` that has a ul with the `text()` with the value `Servers:`

This xpath can be used in your code like this:

```
$xpath   = new \DOMXPath($dom);
$heading = parseToArray($xpath);

print_r($heading);

function parseToArray($xpath)
{
    $xpathQueryUls = '//ul[ancestor-or-self::ul[span[@class="type" and text()="Servers:"]]][span[@class="type"]]';
    $ulElements    = $xpath->query($xpathQueryUls);

    if (!is_null($ulElements)) {
        $resultArray = array();
        foreach ($ulElements as $ulElement) {
            $xpathQueryType       = 'span[@class="type"]';
            $span                 = $xpath->query($xpathQueryType, $ulElement)[0]->nodeValue;
            $xpathQueryLabelNodes = 'li/span[@class="label"][text()]/text()|li/span[@class="label"]/following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()][normalize-space()]';
            /*
             * $xpathQueryLabelNodes has two parts:
             * 1. li/span[@class='label'][text()]/text()
             *      gets the text()-content of the label-span (if there is text)
             * 2. li/span[@class='label']/following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()][normalize-space()]
             *      gets the text()-content of the first following text-node of the label-span (if there is text-content)
             */
            $labels = $xpath->query($xpathQueryLabelNodes, $ulElement);
            foreach ($labels as $label) {
                $resultArray[$span][] = $label->nodeValue;
            }
        }
        return $resultArray;
    }
}

?>
```

With this result:

```
Array
(
    [Servers:] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  (19345)
        
        )

    [Components:] => Array
        (
            [0] => WebSphere:APPLICATION_SERVER
            [1] =>  (18234)
            
        )

    [Applications:] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ipostmutuaintra
            [1] =>  (981)
                
        )

    [Transactions:] => Array
        (
            [0] => /IpostMutuaIntra
            [1] => /IpostMutuaIntra//importo/pdfInoltrata/A_*
        )

)
```

[A link to working example php >=6](https://onlinephp.io/c/7bb22) (Press "Execute Code"-button)

[A link to working example php <=5](https://onlinephp.io/c/5bc14) (Press "Execute Code"-button)

Comment: Ok, but it gives me the error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in variable $span

Comment: I will add  a link to a working example

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: I suppose before 5.6.3? I added an extra link to code with php 5.0

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/39030256/3710053

Comment: I have php 5.3.9 version

Comment: Anyway it worked